# The src attribute only works with a relative path

Tags: html, path, relative-path, src, absolute-path

I added a javascript file to my webpage like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/filename.js"></script>
```

This works fine. However, I then tried to change the relative path to an absolute path, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="/home/name/domains/domain.com/public_html/js/filename.js"></script>
```

This causes this server to respond with a `404 (Not Found)` status.

I'm fairly certain this is the correct absolute path to this file, as importing a certain php file using `require_once()` with a very similar absolute path works without problems. In fact, the PHP function `realpath("../../js/filename.js")` yields `"/home/name/domains/domain.com/public_html/js/filename.js"`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key point is that the `<script>` tag is interpreted **client side** whereas the php include is interpreted **server side**.

Server side, the path will be relative to your file system (being absolute or relative to the current directory)

Client side (=browser side), the path will be relative to the current page url.

If your current page is :
`http://domain:port/page.php`, 
your browser is trying to load `http://domain:port/home/name/domains/domain.com/public_html/js/filename.js` 
which will not be found by the server.

The "root" directory for your server appears to be `/home/name/domains/domain.com/public_html`.

So an "absolute path" from the client view, for your JS file, would be :

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/filename.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need the full path to where the server is storing your information. Your Apache, Nginx, etc. config will take care of creating the root for you and then you need to base off that.

Try changing:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/filename.js"></script>`

to:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/filename.js"></script>`

This will have the code looking for the `/js` folder within the root directory as an absolute path. I presume you have the code stored in the root directory but it's hard to tell without seeing your directory tree.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?>/js/filename.js"></script>
```

I don't see the point in working with absolute paths. You should make your code more dynamic.